# heroku Postgres error - operator does not exist timestamp without timezone = integer

Tags: postgresql, operators, heroku

I am using the following code in my controller:

```
  @monday = (Time.now).at_beginning_of_week

  @friday = 5.days.since(@monday)-1.second

  @sent_emails = ContactEmail.all(:conditions => ['date_sent >= ? and date_sent <= ?', @monday, @friday])
```

Although it works fine on my local sqlite, I have an "operator does not exist timestamp without timezone = integer" error.

I'm not exactly clear what to change.

Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your parameters @monday and @friday are wrong, these have to be of type "timestamp without time zone" but are created as integers, see the errormessage. SQLite doesn't have any datetime-datatypes, so dates are stored as text or integers (unix-timestamps). This is why you don't get an errormessage in SQLite.

Make sure you create timestamps like '2004-10-19 10:23:54' and you will be fine. Another option could be the PostgreSQL-function [to_timestamp()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-formatting.html) to convert your unix-timestamp to a timestamp:

```
@sent_emails = ContactEmail.all(:conditions => ['date_sent >= to_timestamp(?) and date_sent <= to_timestamp(?)', @monday, @friday])
```

Comment: which would you recommend?  converting in postgres or creating the right format for @monday and @friday?  If the latter, how, I looked at the ruby defs for time...not clear what I would do diff...thanks!

Comment: Use the right format, now you can also use a simple index on this column to speed things up.